# Running `mongo` produces `Operation timed out` when using `brew services`

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew, apple-m1

I'm using `brew services` to launch `mongodb-community` on my M1 Mac. However, I'm getting an error `Operation timed out` when trying to run `mongo` or connect to it on a different machine.

According to `brew services ls` it is `started`, and doesn't look to have any errors.

When running `mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf` and trying to connect again, it works fine.

When looking at the `Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist` file everything looks correct:

```
...
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community/bin/mongod</string>
    <string>--config</string>
    <string>/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf</string>
  </array>
...
```

This problem started to happen after I tried to copy the data folder to an external hard drive.

For reference my `/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf` file looks like:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /Volumes/Drive13_A/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Any ideas about why it would fail when using `brew services` but not `mongod` directly?

---

Edit:

After restarting the computer `brew services ls` now reports an error. Looking at the logs I see this entry:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-09T16:18:50.166-06:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file: /Volumes/Drive13_A/mongodb/mongod.lock (Operation not permitted). Ensure the user executing mongod is the owner of the lock file and has the appropriate permissions. Also make sure that another mongod instance is not already running on the /Volumes/Drive13_A/mongodb directory"}}
```

There is no `/Volumes/Drive13_A/mongodb/mongod.lock` file that exists, and I ran `chmod -R 777 /Volumes/Drive13_A/mongodb` (which should fix the permissions), however it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by giving `mongod` permissions in `Security & Privacy`.

System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Files and Folders > `mongod` > Removable Volumes (should be checked)